# sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode: not returning proper CGSize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Unless I am reading the docs wrong, it seems like this method `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` is not returning the proper CGSize. Here's a sample code

```
NSString *someText = @"$";
CGFloat actualFontSize;
CGSize textSize = [someText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedMedium" size:100.0] minFontSize:1.0 actualFontSize:&actualFontSize forWidth:10.0 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

The height of `textSize` returned is what it would be if the font size is **100.0**, not what it'd be at the new reduced font size.

If you then take `actualFontSize` and do `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`:

```
CGSize newTextSize = [someText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedMedium" size:actualFontSize] forWidth:10.0 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

Now `newTextSize` will contain the correct height.

Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue. I have to recalculate the true text height by calling sizeWithFont again with the actual font size as you have done.

Comment: I'd suggest to use the string @"Ay" as a general reference for getting more or less OK line height measurement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your width. Because you have set the minimum font to 1.0 pixels and the width only to 10.0 your textSize will automatically adjust to a lower textSize fitting the 10.0 width that you set yourself.

```
CGSize textSize = [someText 
sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedMedium" size:100.0] 
minFontSize:1.0   //the troublemaker
actualFontSize:&actualFontSize 
forWidth:10.0     //the troublemaker 
lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

The other one you posted will return the proper size because you didn't set the minimum textFont and you put your width just right.

```
CGSize newTextSize = [someText 
sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedMedium" 
size:actualFontSize] 
forWidth:currencyRect.size.width //probably not 10 pixels wide
lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. They are both 10px wide and I do want it to automatically adjust to the lower text size. But I also want the CGSize returned to reflect the actual adjusted size and it is currently not doing that.